# AOP for all methods in a package

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am using AOP for the first time.
 I have written the below AOP code which works fine when i use it to intercept a particular method.

Can somebody guide me - how I can set it up to intercept all methods in a certain package (com.test.model)?

Basically how to setup appcontext.xml.

Also, do i need to  do something like below to call before calling each method?

```
AopClass aoptest = (AopClass) _applicationContext.getBean("AopClass");
aoptest.addCustomerAround("dummy");
```

Can somebody help?

Please let me if some more explanation is needed.

Below is my code:

**Interface:**

```
package com.test.model;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public interface AopInterface {


    @Autowired
    void addCustomerAround(String name);
}
```

**Class:**

```
package com.test.model;

import com.test.model.AopInterface;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Component
public class AopClass implements AopInterface {

    public void addCustomerAround(String name){
        System.out.println("addCustomerAround() is running, args : " + name);
    }
}
```

**AOP:**

```
package com.test.model;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;



@Aspect
public class TestAdvice{


     @Around("execution(* com.test.model.AopInterface.addCustomerAround(..))")
       public void testAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("testAdvice() is running!");


       }
}
```

**appcontext:**

```
<!-- Aspect -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="AopClass" class="com.test.model.AopClass" />
    <bean id="TestAdvice" class="com.test.model.TestAdvice" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put:

```
@Around("execution(* com.test.model..*.*(..))")
```

The format of an execution expression is:

```
execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern declaring-type-pattern? name-pattern(param-pattern) throws-pattern?)
```

where only `ret-type-pattern`, `name-pattern` and `param-pattern` are required, so at least we need an expression like:

```
execution(ret-type-pattern name-pattern(param-pattern))
```

- `ret-type-pattern` matches the return type, `*` for any
- `name-pattern` matches the method name, you can use `*` as wildcard and `..` to indicate sub-package
- `param-pattern` matches the method parameters, `(..)` for any number of parameters

You can find more information here: [10. Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), there are some useful [examples](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples).